# Array reference behaving like a copy

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reference

I have a simple React app with a table of posts:
[image]

In the beginning, the app always has 100 posts.

Here's how I handle DELETE operation:

```
  handleDelete = async post => {
    const oldPosts = this.state.posts;

    const posts = this.state.posts.filter(n => n.id !== post.id);
    this.setState({ posts });

    try {
      await axios.delete(`${apiEndpoint}/${post.id}`);
      console.log(oldPosts);
    } catch (e) {
      alert("There was an error while removing post " + post.id);
    }
  };
```

oldPosts variable contains a REFERENCE to posts array of state. As you can see in the next two lines, I'm updating state with a smaller amount of posts (99 of them). I would expect my oldPosts reference to point to this 99-element array. However, when it's console.logged, I see 100 elements. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect my oldPosts reference to point to this 99-element
>   array. However, when it's console.logged, I see 100 elements. Why is
>   that?

Nice question, let me try to explain. See the case is, array will be stored in some memory location and `this.state.posts` will have the ref to that `array`. You are referencing the same `array` by `oldPosts`, it means `oldPosts` is pointing to array not to `this.state.posts`.

When we update the value of `this.state.posts`, it will have a new ref, ref to newly created `array`, not to old array. But that `oldPosts` will still point to old array.

Even if you assign any value other than an array, it will never effect the value of `oldPosts`.

Check this example, you will get a better idea:

```js
// consider this as state obj
let obj = {
  posts: [1, 2, 3, 4],
}

let oldPosts = obj.posts;
let newPosts = obj.posts.filter(el => el < 4);

// same as setState
obj.posts = newPosts;

// still point to old array
console.log('oldPosts', oldPosts);

// it will have the new array
console.log('obj.posts', obj.posts);

obj.posts = 10;

// now it will have a totally new value
console.log('obj.posts', obj.posts);
```

Check this another example:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let b = a;

/* 
  a and b both points to same array, but if we assign a 
   new value to a, b will still points to array
*/

a = 10;

// by changing the value of a, it will not affect b
console.log('a', a);

// still point to array
console.log('b', b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really nice examples!

Comment: glad, that helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  const oldPosts = this.state.posts;
```

That *copies* the reference to the array into the `oldPost` variable. If the array inside `this.state.posts` get changed, you will see those changes inside `oldPosts`, but if the reference itself gets changed, then `oldPost` and `this.state.posts` point to two different arrays.

Using `.filter` you do create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning 100 `posts` to `oldPosts`. Then you are filtering `posts` to get a new array and saving in state. Filter returns a new array and does not updates the actual array i.e. `oldPosts`. If you want this behavior, you can use `Array.prototype.splice`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your oldPosts state.
 this should work

```
  this.setState({ oldPosts : posts });
```

Thanks

Comment: I didn't intend to do that, but thanks for your input